# On hover, some of my elements move

Tags: html, css

I made this page where I have some buttons up and if I hover on them, the content of my center text field would change. Problem is, on the left and on the right of my center field, I have 2 more text fields but their content has to remain the same but for some reason, when I hover over my buttons, those 2 divs change their position. Any idea why? Also why is the text so asymetric in those 2 divs?

Html:

```
<div class="centru">
    <div class="tohover" id="m1"><a href=#>Home</a></div>
   <div class="tohover" id="m2"><a href=#>Mail</a></div>
   <div class="tohover" id="m3"><a href=#>Sports</a></div>
   <div class="tohover" id="m4"><a href=#>Movies</a></div>
    <div class="centermenu" id="c1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel molestie nulla, eu tincidunt purus. Phasellus eget ligula orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="centermenu" id="c2">
        <p>Phasellus mattis rutrum urna et imperdiet. Ut laoreet feugiat magna non consequat. Cras dictum auctor felis, et aliquam ante vehicula quis. Vivamus quis turpis lectus. Nulla lobortis sem ac purus lacinia finibus. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="centermenu" id="c3">
        <p>Curabitur quis ex mollis, sollicitudin nunc ut, sollicitudin enim. Vestibulum ligula sem, finibus ac enim a, imperdiet efficitur mi.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="centermenu" id="c4">
        <p>Nam laoreet augue id risus pretium efficitur. Suspendisse consequat elementum urna sit amet porta. Proin feugiat suscipit ante, varius sodales dolor vestibulum ac.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="online">
      <p>sdfsfdfsd</pp>
    </div>
   <div class="rightonline">
      <p>sdfsfdfsd</pp>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.centru {
  position: relative;
  height: 700px;
  width: 1500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.tohover {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 73px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #330066;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px
}

.centermenu {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 700px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 260px;
  border: 1px solid #606060;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
}

p {
  padding: 5px;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

.tohover > a {
  color: white;
}

#c1.centermenu {
 display: block;
}

#c2.centermenu {
 display: none;
}

#c3.centermenu {
 display: none;
}

#c4.centermenu {
 display: none;
}

#m1:hover ~ #c1 {
   display: block;
}

#m2:hover ~ #c2 {
   display: block;
}

#m2:hover ~ #c1 {
    display: none;
}

#m3:hover ~ #c3 {
   display: block;
}

#m3:hover ~ #c1 {
   display: none;
}

#m4:hover ~ #c4 {
   display: block;
}

#m4:hover ~ #c1 {
   display: none;
}

.online {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 70px;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  border: 1px solid #606060;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
  font-size: 25px;
}

.rightonline {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: -160px;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  border: 1px solid #606060;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 1017px;
}
```

I'm not sure what code to post. It's not long, here is the snippet http://codepen.io/LisaFort/pen/bpraJq

I only used html and css, no js! Basically I didn't know how to arrange those 3 divs inline so I just played around with the margins. How can I put them inline so they dont affect each other?

Adding a min-height as suggested doesn't fix the problem because if the text gets bigger than the min height, the other divs still move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hej i changed the css a bit to this. The margin left inside .rightonline make that the paragraph moves down. With this css code you only need to change the div position online rightonline and centermenu.

i hope this helps.

```
#main {
  background-color: #330066;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
}

#mainlist {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#mainlist:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#centerer {
  positiong: absolute;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

#image {
  height: 45px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  position: relative;
}

.textbox { 
    background: transparent url(http://html-generator.weebly.com/files/theme/input-text-8.png) repeat-x; 
    border: 1px solid #999; 
    outline:0; 
    height: 30px; 
    width: 500px;
  } 

.button {
    background-color: #0080F0; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    width: 140px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: -16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

#texter {
  display: table-cell; 
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

.centru {
  position: relative;
  height: 700px;
  width: 1500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.tohover {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 73px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #330066;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px
}

p {
  padding: 5px;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

.tohover > a {
  color: white;
}

#c1.centermenu {
 display: block;
}

#c2.centermenu {
 display: none;
}

#c3.centermenu {
 display: none;
}

#c4.centermenu {
 display: none;
}

#m1:hover ~ #c1 {
   display: block;
}

#m2:hover ~ #c2 {
   display: block;
}

#m2:hover ~ #c1 {
    display: none;
}

#m3:hover ~ #c3 {
   display: block;
}

#m3:hover ~ #c1 {
   display: none;
}

#m4:hover ~ #c4 {
   display: block;
}

#m4:hover ~ #c1 {
   display: none;
}

.centermenu {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid #606060;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
}

.online {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  border: 1px solid #606060;
  color: black;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
  font-size: 25px;
  postion: relative;
  float: left;
}

.rightonline {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  border: 1px solid #606060;
  height: auto;
  color: black;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the element `.centermenu` doesn't have a fixed height and it uses the the height based on the contents. So, give it a `min-height` of `100px`.

```
.centermenu {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

**Note:** I would suggest using `min-height` because, if your contents, at any point of time go beyond the height, it might look good, as `height` might restrict the layout.

**CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqxYmP**

> *ps: I won't recommend stripping Yahoo!'s website without their permission.* `;)`

Comment: Sorry. That was not the idea. It's just trying to replicate the "change text on hover" using only CSS. I'm not going to rebuild all their site or anything. The min-height thing fixes it for as long as the text doesn't go beyond 100px either. After 100px, the other 2 divs move again. But any idea why the first div's text has a dumb position?

Comment: @Melye77 Use like `120px`. I do understand. You can check the height of individual elements and get the min-height being set for the largest one.

Comment: Check this out http://codepen.io/LisaFort/pen/bpraJq See? I added a min-heigh of 100 but when I go over the Movies... it's still broken

Comment: Not to mention that the higher the min-height, the more broken the online div looks. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Melye77 Lemme check.

Answer (score 0):

Since the length of your text changes (and the amount of lines alters) the height of your content div changes as well, causing all elements afterwards to move down.

An easy fix would be to give your `.centermenu` class some fixed height.

If that's not enought you might think about positioning your lower `div`s with `position: absolute`

Comment: Please don't advice about using `position: absolute` here.

Comment: Depending on his aims this might be exactly what he needs (for instance if he wants to pop in some hint note)

Comment: I understand but if you take a look, my online div is broken too. If I grow the height, that div is growing too and the text in it has a weird position, no idea why

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish and I currently don't have the time to look at it in detail (if there is still no solution in about 4 hours I'll have time). Depending on your needs a look at the [Holy Grail](http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail) might take you to the right direction (just search for "holy grail css", there are many good sources).